# How to use `AccountIndex` with `MultiAddress` in a parachain?

Tags: parachain, multiaddress

In [this pull request #19](https://github.com/DataHighway-DHX/DataHighway-Parachain/pull/19) I am trying to merge the following features into a working **parachain** based on the substrate-parachain-template in this [pull request #17 here](https://github.com/DataHighway-DHX/DataHighway-Parachain/pull/17):

- Added `AccountIndex` to the address [here](https://github.com/DataHighway-DHX/DataHighway-Parachain/pull/19/files#diff-0ec06ea58bd455f09ce6b3bb4c2c1c0d37bda51c1e1be2151c560c9c973959ecR128) so it became the following. Previously it was `MultiAddress<AccountId, ()>;`)

```
pub type Address = MultiAddress<AccountId, AccountIndex>;
```

- Added `CreateSignedTransaction` [here](https://github.com/DataHighway-DHX/DataHighway-Parachain/pull/19/files#diff-0ec06ea58bd455f09ce6b3bb4c2c1c0d37bda51c1e1be2151c560c9c973959ecR543). Its purpose is described in [this answer](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/724/what-is-the-purpose-of-createsignedtransactionlocalcall)
- Added `SigningTypes` [here](https://github.com/DataHighway-DHX/DataHighway-Parachain/pull/19/files#diff-0ec06ea58bd455f09ce6b3bb4c2c1c0d37bda51c1e1be2151c560c9c973959ecR585)
- Used `SendTransactionTypes` [here](https://github.com/DataHighway-DHX/DataHighway-Parachain/pull/19/files#diff-0ec06ea58bd455f09ce6b3bb4c2c1c0d37bda51c1e1be2151c560c9c973959ecR590)

But it generates the errors shown [here](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/ltfschoen/63b0d904d221a93607e68322ae1c4dde/raw/df97f57f0c6322fcdd1a25fa3e4ec983cba64632/error-datahighway-multiaddress-accountindex.md).

However, there weren't any errors when I previously made the same changes in the **standalone chain** based on the substrate-node-template (a separate repository) in [this pull request #215](https://github.com/DataHighway-DHX/node/pull/215/files#diff-0ec06ea58bd455f09ce6b3bb4c2c1c0d37bda51c1e1be2151c560c9c973959ecR1446).

What steps could be taken to try to fix the errors?

How would you satisfying all the unsatisfied trait bounds so the functions `execute_block`, `initialize_block`, `apply_extrinsic`, `finalize_block`, `validate_transaction`, `offchain_worker` may be called?

How would you make `struct UncheckedExtrinsic` satisfy trait `Checkable<ChainContext<Runtime>>`?

How would you implement trait `Checkable<ChainContext<Runtime>>` for trait bound `UncheckedExtrinsic<MultiAddress<sp_runtime::AccountId32, u32>...` in `register_validate_block`, which is required by bound `validate_block`?

Where is the implementation for `UncheckedExtrinsic<Address, Call, Signature, Extra> as Checkable<Lookup>>` that it says it found?

Update 15th March: I don't think the changes in [pull request #19](https://github.com/DataHighway-DHX/DataHighway-Parachain/pull/19) are necessary, because Kilt's Spiritnet parachain codebase [here](https://github.com/KILTprotocol/mashnet-node/tree/develop/runtimes) that has already live also uses dependencies from Substrate branch 'polkadot-v0.9.17', but even though they are using pallets like pallet_indices, they haven't added `AccountIndex` to `MultiAddress`, and they aren't using `CreateSignedTransaction`, `SigningTypes`, or `SendTransactionTypes`. Similarly with the live Zeitgeist parachain codebase [here](https://github.com/zeitgeistpm/zeitgeist/) isn't using it either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your `frame_system::Config` this line :

```
    type Lookup = AccountIdLookup<AccountId, ()>;
```

needs to say

```
    type Lookup = AccountIdLookup<AccountId, AccountIndex>;
```

This should probably fix your issue.